# Update an imported repo from github to bitbucket

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, updates

I've imported a repo from GitHub to Bitbucket using bitbucket's *import repository* option. It has imported all the branches, tags, commits etc.

Now, the original repo has changed and new branches/tags/commits have been created in the original repo. How do I update my bitbucket's repo at par with the Github's repo?

PS: I can delete the bitbucket repo & re-mirror the Github's repo. But, I'd like to know an alternate way to update the bitbucket repo with the diff.

PPS: I can pull the latest master to my local & then push it to the butbucket's master but I want to push all the new branches/tags also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way, if you don't have made and push new commits on your own is to:

- clone the github repo
- add the bitbucket one as a remote

  ```
  git remote add bb /url/to/bitbucket/repo
  ```
- [push to it with the `--mirror` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---mirror):

  ```
  git push --mirror bb
  ```

That will push everything (branches *and* tags)

In that case, it will help if your work on BitBucket is done in a dedicated branch instead of a branch common between the BitBucket et the GitHub repo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to do it in bitbucket without cloning the entire repo? Like the _import repo_ thing?

Comment: Not that I know of. But once you have cloned the repo, any update will be incremental and fast

Comment: Warning: this method could get rid of all of your branches in the BitBucket repo. A safer way is to clone the gihub repo, switch to the master branch, add the remote, and ONLY push to the master on BitBucket.

Comment: @MohammadTomaraei I agree. I mentioned the --mirror option because the OP specified they could delete the BitBucket repo and re-mirror the GitHub repo.